# Page not redirecting although username and password are correct in cpanel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I created php web application and it is working in my localhost.In addition to that it was working more than one year in cpanel hosting and i change domain and hosting provider. Now i am unable to login to my system. it does not show any error. what i can understand is session is not creating properly. when i went dashboard, it will redirect to again same login page.

Because of Session error, i created file which has only `session` and just `if statement`. it is working fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $user_name = (isset($_POST['txt_username']) ? $_POST['txt_username'] : null);
        $password = md5($_POST['txt_password']);
        if (!empty($user_name) && !empty($password)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE User_Name='$user_name' && Password='$password'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($row = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
         //header("location:htdocs/dashbd.php");

           // echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
         //   echo "<script>location='htdocs/dashbd.php'</script>";
           // echo 'alert("User name or Password is Incorrect");';
            echo 'window.location = "htdocs/dashbd.php";';
          //  echo '</script>';
           // } else {
          //      echo"error";
          if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
              header("location:htdocs/dashbd.php");
          echo 'window.location = "htdocs/dashbd.php";';

    }
            }
        } else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'alert("User name or Password is Incorrect");';
            echo 'window.location = "index.php";';
            echo '</script>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
       // echo 'alert("Username And Password Cannot Be Empty");';
      //  echo'getElementById("#feedback").innerHTML="mukuth nene";';
        //echo 'window.location = "index.php";';
        echo '</script>';
    }

?>
```

when user name and password is correct it needs to redirect to htdocs/dashboard.php. in current situation wont.

Comment: in order to use sessions you have to have `session_start();` before any other output. It doesn't appear you're doing so. I think there may be a PHP config setting to always start sessions (which may explain why it worked before) but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: `htdocs` is usually your web root directory

Comment: session_start() is there. i forgot to put it here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard , Little Bobby   yes. agree. but it has no valuable data. And i develop this when i was young in coding.

Comment: @charlietfl, no its is located in inside of public-html/web-app/htdocs/. Even i try to redirect to google.com it wont work.

Comment: if the $row return the user object ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI yes

Comment: do you have **start_session** in dashbd.php ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI yes. It is working fine in localhost

Comment: can you check using **<?php header('Location: /dashbd.php'); ?>** instead

Comment: problem is redirecting. even this code not work 
'if(!empty($_POST['txt_username'])){
        header('Location: /dashbd.php');
    }'